# Keep scroll position when you return back and change routes angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

I load some results of employees and I am using pagination 20 results per page. When I scroll on the last one of the first page I click on this and the user is redirected to another page, when the user clicks the back button they return back to search results but the scroll position has been lost. Any recommendations of how can I maintain it?

Comment: ohmy this is my exact problem, but mine is happening in the child component so I can't use the scroll position restoration thing

Answer (score 2):

Angular has some extra options you can apply when importing your Router Module, which may suit your requirements.

https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#scrollPositionRestoration

They have an example for component specific scrolling. I have never tried it myself, but it seems to match what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this into you're `app.component.ts` file do the trick, *as said by wingnod*.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(router: Router, viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter((e: Event): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll)
    ).subscribe(e => {
      if (e.position) {
        // backward navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
      } else if (e.anchor) {
        // anchor navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
      } else {
        // forward navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

> The reason of this behavior is that page didn't already render and scrollToPosition no have effect.
> There are not a good hack with timeout but it works. [DrDager](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547#issuecomment-630736014)

#### Note

Angular have actually an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547) regarding this problem

Comment: The issue on the Angular repo is closed but not resolved in my opinion. I used your workaround and it works well. I hope this will be fixed at some point!