# Scroll position save and restore scroll position once back I am on my position in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, scroll-position, maintainscrollpositionon

I am trying this but it's not working. I am implementing management software do and I need this solution

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})
```

Right now I am on the page in the last position okay once I am clicking and navigating to the second
page once I am back on how to be in the last position.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep scroll position when you return back and change routes angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282417/keep-scroll-position-when-you-return-back-and-change-routes-angular-5)